# Monitor not allowing me to select the correct display resolution

Tags: windows-7, display

I have an Acer X193W monitor and the display settings in Windows 7 are not displaying the correct resolution so that I can use i. My monitor supports 1440 x 900, but it is currently using a 1280 x 720 and the option for 1440 x 900 isn't there. I am using [Windows 7 Home Premium x64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Main_editions).

when adding my Nvidia Geforce FX5200 I had the option to use 1440 x 900 which means a problem with the onboard graphics chipset driver. Is there a way that I can update this even though it says it has the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolutions supported by a monitor & resolutions supported by a video card may not necessarily coincide.

An updated video driver /may/ provide additional resolutions.

Comment: everytime i try and update the drivers it says i have the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the desktop, select *Screen resolution*, select *Advanced settings*, select the *Monitor* tab and in there you should see a check box to "Hide modes that this monitor cannot display".

Take note of the warning in the box before you decide to do it.

Comment: not made a difference at all

Answer (score 0):

I tried all sorts of stuff, and finally nailed it in win10 by right clicking desktop, display settings, advanced display settings, display adapter properties for display 1 (showed my LG monitor correctly - which required earlier an automatic driver update which was successful - as it had shown "generic monitor" earlier), then in that final list, my correct resolutions were hiding. Chose right one, and bang! Worked.